# PowerCLI Syntax: copy-harddisk

Tags: powershell, vmware-esx, vmware-vmdk

Whats the correct syntax for coping a vmdk with PowerCLI? I'd like to do the same as vmkfstools -i

Get-HardDisk Machine1 | Copy-HardDisk "[DS] Machine2/test.vmdk"

Produces:
Copy-HardDisk : 21.01.2010 17:59:57    Copy-HardDisk    5285a123-e8b0-06df-984f-6ce1f7c0e080    The operation for the entity  failed with the followi
ng message: "General fault caused by file.
One of the parameters supplied is invalid"

Comment: You can try the community forums here: http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vsphere/automationtools/windows_toolkit.  I have PowerCLI loaded locally, and checked the help file, but don't have access to my ESXi server currently to double-check.

Comment: Thanks Marko, thats what i did (See my Answer below) By the way: The copy command fails on (at least unlicenced/free) ESXi.. seems just to work on ESX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After troubleshooting with help of the VMWare community i found that i need to give the parameter: DestinationStorageFormat Thin with the command.
Not sure yet why Thick does not work...

A proper Error Message would saved me a lot of troubleshooting time ;-)